# How to get cookies after POST request in Android?

Tags: android, cookies, android-asynctask

this is the doInBackground method of my class that extends AsyncTask to do a POST request

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    Log.d("HTTP", "URL:" + arg0[0]);
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);

    try {
        // Add your data
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(login)); 

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        //to Log the response headers
        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            Header h = headers[i];
            Log.i("Header","Header names: "+h.getName());
            Log.i("Header", "Header Value: "+h.getValue());
        }

        int respCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.d("HTTP", "POST:"+arg0[0]+" Risposta Server dopo invio: "+respCode);

        return respCode;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Gestire nel codice finale
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this is the logcat:

> > 01-18 14:44:26.532: I/Header(591): Header names: Date
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.543: I/Header(591): Header Value: Sat, 18 Jan 2014 14:44:21 GMT
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.543: I/Header(591): Header names: Server
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.543: I/Header(591): Header Value: Apache
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.543: I/Header(591): Header names: Set-Cookie
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.543: I/Header(591): Header Value: session_id=29ae962bcc7cbb648c4b2e35b2a7b4f6; path=/; domain=.forumcommunity.net; HttpOnly
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.543: I/Header(591): Header names: X-Frame-Options
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.553: I/Header(591): Header Value: DENY
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.553: I/Header(591): Header names: Set-Cookie
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.553: I/Header(591): Header Value: member_id=8712154; expires=Sun, 
>   18-Jan-2015 14:44:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.forumcommunity.net; HttpOnly
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.553: I/Header(591): Header names: Set-Cookie
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.572: I/Header(591): Header Value: pass_hash=83e8e0213aa10058b2d014bc0331598d6076bd23f145d03b6ee8a31b2eb25e96; expires=Sun,  18-Jan-2015 14:44:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.forumcommunity.net; HttpOnly
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.572: I/Header(591): Header names: Vary
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.572: I/Header(591): Header Value: Accept-Encoding
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.572: I/Header(591): Header names: P3P
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.582: I/Header(591): Header Value: CP="NOI ADM DEV COM OUR STP"
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.582: I/Header(591): Header names: Connection
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.582: I/Header(591): Header Value: close
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.602: I/Header(591): Header names: Transfer-Encoding
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.602: I/Header(591): Header Value: chunked
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.602: I/Header(591): Header names: Content-Type
>
> 01-18 14:44:26.602: I/Header(591): Header Value: text/html; charset=windows-1252

how can I get only the Set-Cookie headers and parse it in a Cookies List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example of accessing the cookies after a HTTP request:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomContext.java

Use this code after `client.execute()` to get the cookies:

`List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();`

Comment: is possible to do the same thing using HttpContext instead HttpClientContext and HttpResponse instead CloseableHttpResponse?

Comment: Yes, those are the same classes, just named differently on Android.